# Access HTML5 audio element which is inside iframe

Tags: html, audio, iframe, mute

I have one index.html, that has one iframe. Inside the iframe I am loading different html pages that each have one audio element. I have one sound mute button on index.html page. I need to access the audio element inside the iframe to mute the audio.

Comment: You mean One button should mute all the audios in the `index.html` page?

Comment: yes, but my audio is in different html pages which i am loading in to iframe.

Comment: So cant you put the *mute* button in the main page and when its clicked mute all the `iframes`.